# Sharepoint Designer: Update Item: Moving documents from one folder to another

Tags: list, designer-workflow, designer

I have SharePoint Designer 2010,.

I have been trying to wrap my head around the workflows and particularly the ability to move files [Word, Excel, etc.] from one folder within a library to another. I need to be able to pass said files from a directory like

website\VacationPaperwork\Supervisor

to

website\VacationPaperwork\Director

to

website\VacationPaperwork\HumanResources

without deleting them in the process.

I think I can tie the each categorical workflow to the SP website to allow an approve/deny function for each workspace when it does complete, but actually moving files using the workflow is not clicking for me.

Any ideas?